# Finding words in text file to extract data using C++

Tags: c++, text-files, automator

I am trying to find the total amount of time spent doing a certain activity with C++ and Mac Automator (you do not need to know 
Automator to help me). I am using Mac Automator to output a text file using "Event Summary" and "New Text File" actions. It outputs a text file like this:
[Viewable text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0I6p3B-4pUnazJJVVY1RUxjVW8/view?usp=sharing)

I am currently struggling over something very trivial; I cannot accurately find the words "Time" and "Date" in the text file. If I cannot find the words "Time" and "Date" I cannot begin processing the total amount of time spent doing that activity or whether that activity went over midnight (I sometimes work into the ams). So far I think I have spent four hours with mixed results. Any feedback would be appreciated.

The code below is the code I am using at the moment. I can find the word "Time" and "Date" at the very start of the file, or if a ':' is in front of the word "Time" or "Date", but when it is on a different line the programs fails:

```
cout << "Reading from the file...." << endl;
infile.open("calendar workflow text.txt");
while(infile.getline(buff, BUFFSIZE, ':')){ //reads everything
    cout << buff << endl; // prints everything
    if(strcmp("Time",buff)==0){
        cout<<"Time found in text\n"<<endl;
    }
    else if (strcmp("Date",buff)==0){
        cout<<"Date found in text\n"<<endl;
    }
}
infile.close();
cout<<"Total Time in all events: "<<sumtime<<" hrs"<<endl;
return (0);
```

If you want the automator workflow I can give it to you.

Comment: Use `strstr` instead of `strcmp`. The latter is for exact matches only.

Comment: Doesn't [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) work for you?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ sorry I might have used "find" in a bad context. I want it's position not just the whether or not it is in the text so I can use the time values for further calculations.

Comment: @JordanStewart If you would have read the link, it's stated there: ***Return value***  
_Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no such substring is found._

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Oh sry. That was dumb of me. Thanks. I just got confused by the examples.

Comment: I would use infile.getline(buff, BUFFSIZE) so that you read a line at a time, instead of stopping at colons.  For this file format, it looks like Time and Date are always at the beginning of a line, which then makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few assumptions that you need to check for:

1. Is "Time" always going to start at the very first character position? No space or tab before you see the word "Time"?
2. Can there be multiple "Time" words in the same line?
3. Can another word appear before "Time"?

`strcmp("Time",buff)` assumes that your entire string "buff" has just one word in it "Time".
That is not what you want. If assumption 1 is true, you can simply do

```
if strncmp(buff, "Time", 4) == 0 {
      // do something, as you found time
}
```

Otherwise, for a generic position, you can use `strstr(buff, "Time")`, for a substring match where "Time" could be anywhere in the string. Once you get the position, skip over exactly the number of characters to get to the value for time. Extract that and perform your calculations.

Typically, in parsing files, you will have to have to some allowance for spaces/tabs etc. Otherwise, the code becomes too brittle and can fail testcases that deviate ever so slightly.